# GHCI stack overflow on `instance Show MyType`

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow, typeclass, ghci

Why do I get stack overflow trying to do this in GHCI (version 7.6.2)? How can I derive a typeclass instance during a GHCI session or why is this not possible?

```
*Main> data T = T Int
*Main> let t = T 42
*Main> instance Show T
*Main> t
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

I know I can use `deriving Show` at the type declaration, but this trick would be useful for inspecting types loaded from files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to implement at least one of `show` or `showsPrec` for the instance to work. In the class, there are default implementations of `show` using `showsPrec` (via `shows`), and of `showsPrec` using `show`:

```
showsPrec _ x s = show x ++ s
show x          = shows x ""
```

and

```
shows           =  showsPrec 0
```

so

```
instance Show T
```

creates a looping instance. Calling `show` calls `showsPrec`, which calls `show`, which ...

With the `StandaloneDeriving` language extension, you can

```
ghci> :set -XStandaloneDeriving
ghci> deriving instance Show T
```

derive the instance at the prompt.

Comment: Added how you can derive the instance at the prompt. You can't do it simpler than that, as far as I know.

Comment: You can do a macro `:def doShow \typeName -> return $ ":set -XStandaloneDeriving\nderiving instance Show " ++ typeName` (probably into your `.ghci` file), then, only need to write `Prelude>:doShow T` :D